# using stored procedure parameter as join condition within procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, stored-procedures

What I want here is, using the parameter @PackageId as join condition parameter from Packages table while joining Packages table with the Devices(somewhere around FROM Packages Join Devices on Packages.PackageId=Devices.PackageId)

```
create PROC [dbo].[Usp_MissingPackageList] 
(@DeviceName AS varchar(50),
@PackageId as int )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Packages.PackageId
        ,Packages.DisplayName
        ,Packages.PublishedBy
        ,convert(VARCHAR(10),Packages.PublishedOn, 101) PublishedOn
    FROM Packages Join Devices on Packages.PackageId=Devices.PackageId
    join [dbo].[PersonalizationStatuses] on Devices.SerialKey=PersonalizationStatuses.DeviceSerialNo
    where (Packages.PackageId>@PackageID) and (Packages.FlightType=PersonalizationStatuses.FleetType or Packages.FlightType='Common')
    ORDER BY PackageId ASC
END
```

My requirement is to get all tha packages from the Package table having PackageId>@PackageId

Comment: I am not clear what you want here you can have if you want to get matches only you can Join Devices on Packages.PackageId=@packageid and drop the where (Packages.PackageId>@PackageID) .. or Join Devices on Packages.PackageId=Devices.PackageId and change the where to where (Packages.PackageId = @PackageID).

Comment: @P.Salmon sorry for the late reply,My requirement is to join the Packages table with Devices when Packages.PackageId(= @PackageId)=Devices.PackageId. and then to get all the packages from the Packages table,whose  PackageId >@PackageId and other conditions in the where clouse are also satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Use along with Join

```
  create PROC [dbo].[Usp_MissingPackageList] 
    (@DeviceName AS varchar(50),
    @PackageId as int )
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT Packages.PackageId
            ,Packages.DisplayName
            ,Packages.PublishedBy
            ,convert(VARCHAR(10),Packages.PublishedOn, 101) PublishedOn
        FROM Packages Join Devices on Packages.PackageId=Devices.PackageId AND (Packages.PackageId>@PackageID)
        join [dbo].[PersonalizationStatuses] on Devices.SerialKey=PersonalizationStatuses.DeviceSerialNo
        where  (Packages.FlightType=PersonalizationStatuses.FleetType or Packages.FlightType='Common')
        ORDER BY PackageId ASC
    END
```